# If not closed then Auto close or auto format html tag in dynamic content in razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008, razor, c#-4.0

below content has pulled from database

```
<div class="main"><div class="col1">content</div>
```

in above example main div has not closed in my database so I want to close it.

I have simply add in my razor view page

```
@Html.Raw(a.shortDesc)
```

but my page has disturbed. so please suggest me.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the `HtmlAgilityPack` (https://html-agility-pack.net/) to fix the HTML before you render it out using `@Html.Raw` in your view.

In the `ShortDesc` property of your ViewModel, you could do something like this:

```
private string _shortDesc;
public string ShortDesc
{
    get 
    {
        var doc = new HtmlDocument();
        doc.LoadHtml(_shortDesc);
        return doc.DocumentNode.OuterHtml;
    }
    set 
    {
        this._shortDesc = value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
@{
var data = @a.shortDesc+"</div>"; 
}
@Html.Raw(@data)
```

Comment: Although this is a quick fix for this particular piece of HTML, this could potentially cause issues with other, valid, pieces of HTML.

Comment: Add Closed div string into your data from database